# NSBitmapImageRep load image

Tags: objective-c, nsbitmapimagerep, nsimagerep

i'm quite new to objective C and followed some instructions i found, but at the moment i got stuck.

i am trying to load an image with the following code:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *img;
img = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

"filename" is a valid pointer. But the compiler tells me:

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSBitmapImageRep *' from 'NSImageRep * _Nullable'
```

What am i missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: what kind of image is it? `filename` may be a valid NSString object but are you certain it's pointing to the correct file?

Comment: Boris Verebsky solved my problem. I wasn't aware of do explicit typecasting in objective-c :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageRepWithContentsOfFile:` is a factory method. According documentation, it returns "An initialized instance of an NSImageRep subclass, or nil if the image data could not be read." From `NSImageRep.h`: "If sent to a subclass, does this just for the types understood by that subclass.". So, you need only cast result to specified type:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imgRep = (NSBitmapImageRep *)[NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

Note that usually you doesn't need to create `NSBitmapImageRep` instances yourself, and can use `NSImage`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. As i had written before: i am very new to objective c and wasn't aware of this casting problem.